# samsung gear live audio encoding

Tags: audio-recording, wear-os

I'm currently working on an Android Wear app, and I'm looking toward audio recording. I've followed the tutorial on the Android developper website, and it works well on my Nexus 7, but not on the Samsung Gear Live I have for testing. The application just goes crashing all the time.

Digging a bit into the problem, I might have figured out that it was a problem with 2 parameters for the recorder to work: either the `OutputFormat`, or the `AudioEncoder`. I tried pairing and trying all the `OutputFormat` and `AudioEncoder` available, but without any luck.

So here's my question: did someone encounter the same problem? And if so, did you find the right combination of Format/Encoder?

I don't paste my code as it's exactly the same as in the documentation. Here is the link if you want to have a look: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/audio-capture.html

Thank you in advance for your answers and your time :)

Comment: I have been digging a bit more, and found some... interesting / disturbing information... When using AAC encoding with ARM_NB or ARM_WB, the application doesn't crash. Instead, when the `start()` method is called on my `MediaRecorder`, I have a `mediaserver died` error.

Comment: Did you try the DEFAULT codec? My understanding is that there are no compression codecs on Android Wear, and so you need to capture the audio data with no compression, and it should work for you, but I have not tested this so I don't have a sample.

Comment: Yes I tried the DEFAULT too, but it's not working either unfortunately. I'll try with no compression, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

The root problem is that you cannot use MediaRecorder, even though the [Android audio capture example does](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/audio-capture.html), but instead you need to use the [AudioRecord](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html) class.

Also, I'd recommend streaming the raw data back to your phone to assemble it into an audio file as that is very thorny on a wearable.

For more, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26177703/1783829) for more.

I have included a sample below that I got working.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.AudioFormat;
import android.media.AudioRecord;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.support.wearable.view.WatchViewStub;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.View;

import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getName();
    private static final int SPEECH_REQUEST_CODE = 1;

    private static final int RECORDER_SAMPLERATE = 44100;
    private static final int RECORDER_CHANNELS = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_STEREO;
    private static final int RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;

    private TextView mTextView;
    private AudioRecord recorder;
    private int bufferSize = 0;
    private Thread recordingThread = null;
    private volatile boolean isRecording;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.v(TAG, "Creating MainActivity");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final WatchViewStub stub = (WatchViewStub) findViewById(R.id.watch_view_stub);
        stub.setOnLayoutInflatedListener(new WatchViewStub.OnLayoutInflatedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLayoutInflated(WatchViewStub stub) {
                mTextView = (TextView) stub.findViewById(R.id.text);
            }
        });

        bufferSize =
                AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(RECORDER_SAMPLERATE,
                        RECORDER_CHANNELS, RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING);
    }

    public void handleRecordButtonClick(View view) {
        startAudioCapture();
    }

    public void handleStopButtonClick(View view) {
        stopAudioCapture();
    }

    private void startAudioCapture() {
        Log.v(TAG, "Starting audio capture");
        recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
                RECORDER_SAMPLERATE, RECORDER_CHANNELS, RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING,     bufferSize);
        if (recorder.getState() == AudioRecord.STATE_INITIALIZED) {
            recorder.startRecording();
            isRecording = true;
            Log.v(TAG, "Successfully started recording");

            recordingThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    processRawAudioData();
                }
            }, "AudioRecorder Thread");

            recordingThread.start();
        } else {
            Log.v(TAG, "Failed to started recording");
        }
    }

    private void stopAudioCapture() {
        Log.v(TAG, "Stop audio capture");
        recorder.stop();
        isRecording = false;
        recorder.release();
    }

    private void processRawAudioData() {
        byte data[] = new byte[bufferSize];
        int read = 0;
        while(isRecording) {
            read = recorder.read(data, 0, bufferSize);

            if(AudioRecord.ERROR_INVALID_OPERATION != read) {
                Log.v(TAG, "Successfully read " + data.length + " bytes of audio");
            }
        }
    }
}
```